# Clock in Notification Area Does Not Update

Tags: clock

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 with Android 4.2.2 that is behaving strangely.  The clock on the notification bar refuses to update while I'm using the tablet or even while it's sleeping.  The only times it updates is when you go into date/time settings and change the time or when the tablet goes to sleep and wakes up again.  Another symptom is that none of the apps have updated in about two months.

I thought this clock (which is located in the notification bar (right next to the battery indicator and the wi-fi signal indicator) is part of the Android O/S.  It seems strange that the clock would just stop updating.  Any advice you could give (short of resetting the whole device) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem with my Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300) running Jelly Bean 4.3. I restart the device quite frequently, but no luck. Normally it's 4-10 minutes off, then the time is suddenly updated. But I kinda hate it when such a simple function is not reliable.
Still looking for some solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was simple.  I just needed to restart the tablet.  It hadn't been restarted in months and I guess that somehow the updating system process got in a weird state.  After doing a reboot (restart) via a hard power off, the clock started working and updates are downloading as normal.  I hope my solution here helps someone else.